# How could I open a hidden partition on a USB driver from an Android tablet?

Tags: file-management, usb-drivers, usb-mass-storage

There is a USB GPT driver. One partition is hidden. How could I open that partition on an Android tablet?

I know I can unhide that partition on Windows system. But can I open it on Android?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: @IrfanLatif Thank you for your information. I'm not going to develop an app. I am just a user. I check the link you give me. It seems like a function.

Comment: Link fixed. [`mount`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html) it if it contains a supported filesystem.

Comment: @IrfanLatif Thank you very much. I will try it.

Comment: On Android, only the primary partition is mounted by VolumeManager. You can access other partitions with 3rd Party app.